# How to define a disk quota for docker containers?

Tags: docker, disk, quota

I'm was faced with the requirement to have disk quotas on docker containers. Specifically I want to limit the amount of data that is not in the layers of base image but in the diff. Googling for "docker disk quota" suggests to use either the [device mapper](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/01/29/docker-device-mapper-resize/) or the btrfs backends. While being able to have quotas in both backends (with different semantics) both have their issues:

- btrfs isn't stable enough for production use
- device mapper only limits the complete container size including the base image but doesn't allow limiting the diff

What is the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is to put the diff directory `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/$CONTAINER_ID` into a sparse loopback mounted ext4 directory. This effectively limits the amount of data a user can store/modify in a container. This is the bash code I use:

```
do_enable_quota() {
    local ID=$1
    local QUOTA_MB=$2

    local LOOPBACK=/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/$ID-loopback
    local LOOPBACK_MOUNT=/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/$ID-loopback-mount
    local DIFF=/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/$ID

    docker stop -t=0 $ID
    sudo dd of=$LOOPBACK bs=1M seek=$QUOTA_MB count=0
    sudo mkfs.ext4 -F $LOOPBACK
    sudo mkdir -p $LOOPBACK_MOUNT
    sudo mount -t ext4 -n -o loop,rw $LOOPBACK $LOOPBACK_MOUNT
    sudo rsync -rtv $DIFF/ $LOOPBACK_MOUNT/
    sudo rm -rf $DIFF
    sudo mkdir -p $DIFF
    sudo umount $LOOPBACK_MOUNT
    sudo rm -rf $LOOPBACK_MOUNT
    sudo mount -t ext4 -n -o loop,rw $LOOPBACK $DIFF
    docker start $ID    
}
```

This approach works perfectly for me but the drawback is that I need to wrap the "start", "stop" and "rm" commands to take the mount into account.

Comment: would you have an example how to get this script to work. In my case, only want to limit the ubuntu:14:04 container size to a few MiB, and have the container created.

Comment: I get these error after running cmd: $ do_enable_quota 91e54dfb11794fad694460162bf0cb0a4fa710cfa3f60979c177d920813e267c 20

Comment: sent 177 bytes  received 50 bytes  454.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
Error response from daemon: no such id: 91e54dfb11794fad694460162bf0cb0a4fa710cfa3f60979c177d920813e267c
Error: failed to start containers: [91e54dfb11794fad694460162bf0cb0a4fa710cfa3f60979c177d920813e267c]

Comment: have you completed working approach? Container specific disk quota, may be limiting inodes.

Answer (score 1):

ZFS is also a great deal: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/zfs-driver/

This way you can manage your disk pools with 'zpool' command line.

For example, to create '***just a bunch of vdisk***':

```
[root@localhost /]# mkdir /dsk
[root@localhost /]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dsk/disk1 bs=1M count=750
[root@localhost /]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dsk/disk2 bs=1M count=750
[root@localhost /]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dsk/disk3 bs=1M count=750
[root@localhost /]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dsk/disk4 bs=1M count=750
```

Ok, we have four disks of 750M each one. Now create one single ZFS pool:

```
[root@localhost /]# zpool create CIALINUX /dsk/disk{1,2,3,4}
```

Now we have a volume named CIALINUX, with ***almost 3GB*** automatically mounted in our / directory:

```
[root@localhost /]# df -h |grep CIALINUX

CIALINUX 2,9G 18K 2,9G 1% /CIALINUX
```

Other commands you can explore by yourself are:

```
# zpool list
# zpool status
# zpool status -x
# zpool destroy CIALINUX
```

Important: This last one 'destroys' your pool. Please pay attention to it.

Once you have your zfs pools, just place your files attached as docker volumes inside /zpool-mounted-directory for each container.

Hope this help community.

Comment: Note this is not a kind of software RAID, you have no four disks writing distributed I/O so your performance will be not so rich as a RAID volume.